# Run rule from second store

Tags: vba, outlook-2016

I want to run a rule from a macro/button in ribbon instead of going through all the clicks needed to "Run rules now" manually. Using Outlook 2016.

My Outlook rule is stored in the second store and not the default store.

The MsgBox is prompted, so the rule is found but it is not executed, and the e-mails in target are not moved.

```vb
Sub RunRule()
    Dim rules As Outlook.rules
    
    Set rules = Application.Session.Stores(2).GetRules()
    
    rules.Item("kundeordre").Execute ShowProgress:=True
    
    MsgBox rules.Item("kundeordre")
End Sub
```

The rules in Outlook:
[image: The rules]

Comment: The code **as it** is should run! I mean, the rule is executed. I would suggest you to edit the rule and **better check in which circumstances the rule in discussion should work**... I think, there must be a mistake. I would suggest you to make a simpler (testing) rule and run it. After seeing working, you can easily delete it.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for your comment. The thing is just that when using the "Run rules now" through the ribbon menu it works as expected. It's simply strange.

Comment: Does the rule in discussion work on Inbox or on all its subfolders, too? Try using the other  `Excecute` parameters. See [here](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-rules-now-using-macro/) which are them and an example of using.

Comment: In the link posted above, check also, `Sub RunRulesSecondary()`, maybe the rule in discussion is not in the second store, even if it is enumerated there, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rules in a non-default store, specify the folder.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunRule()

    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rule.execute
    
    Dim olRules As rules
    
    Dim myRule As Rule
    Dim myRuleName As String
        
    Dim olStore As Store
    Dim olFolder As Folder
    
    Set olStore = Session.Stores(2)
    Debug.Print olStore
    
    With olStore
        Set olRules = .GetRules()
        Set olFolder = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    End With
    
    myRuleName = "kundeordre"
     
    For Each myRule In olRules
        Debug.Print "myRule " & myRule
        If myRule = myRuleName Then
            ' Folder required for non-default store
            myRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=olFolder
            MsgBox myRule & " executed in " & olStore
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```